# Android upload pdf file to server

Tags: java, php, android, pdf, upload

I know there's already lots of question and tutorial of my question. But I failed to get any tutorial to upload file other than images.

I followed an example and managed to upload an image successfully to localhost. But, I want to upload files like pdf, docx, pptx etc. Not restricted to images only.

I followed this tutorial: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-upload-image-to-php-server/

I'm totally beginner in android so I have no idea what am I doing when changing some code from the original. So far, my MainActivity.java as given and the result is 'something went wrong' and crashed when I click the upload button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    String encodedString;
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    String filePath, fileName;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_FILE = 1;
    TextView viewFileName;@
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Set Cancelable as False
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
            // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            // Start the Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_FILE);
        }
        // When Image is selected from Gallery
        @
    Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            viewFileName.setText("File Name: \n" + data.getData().getLastPathSegment() +
                "\n");
            try {
                // When an Image is picked
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
                    null != data) {
                    // Get the Image from data
                    Uri selectedFile = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {
                        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
                    };
                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedFile,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                    // Set the Image in ImageView
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
                    // Get the Image's file name
                    String fileNameSegments[] = filePath.split("/");
                    fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
                    // Put file name in Async Http Post Param which will used in Php web app
                    params.put("filename", fileName);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked any file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            }
        }
        // When Upload button is clicked
    public void uploadImage(View v) {
            // When Image is selected from Gallery
            if (filePath != null && !filePath.equals("")) {
                prgDialog.setMessage("Converting Image to Binary Data");
                prgDialog.show();
                // Convert image to String using Base64
                encodeImagetoString();
                // When Image is not selected from Gallery
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You must select image from gallery before you try to upload",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        // AsyncTask - To convert Image to String
    public void encodeImagetoString() {
        new AsyncTask < Void, Void, String > () {
            protected void onPreExecute() {};@
            Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 3;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50,
                    stream);
                byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
                // Encode Image to String
                encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
                return "";
            }@
            Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                prgDialog.setMessage("Calling Upload");
                // Put converted Image string into Async Http Post param
                params.put("image", encodedString);
                // Trigger Image upload
                triggerImageUpload();
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
    public void triggerImageUpload() {
            makeHTTPCall();
        }
        // Make Http call to upload Image to Php server
    public void makeHTTPCall() {
        prgDialog.setMessage("Invoking Php");
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        // Don't forget to change the IP address to your LAN address. Port no as well.
        client.post("http://10.16.36.144:8080/imgupload/upload_image.php",
            params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                // When the response returned by REST has Http
                // response code '200'
                @
                Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        // Hide Progress Dialog
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // When the response returned by REST has Http
                    // response code other than '200' such as '404',
                    // '500' or '403' etc
                    @
                Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                    String content) {
                    // Hide Progress Dialog
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    // When Http response code is '404'
                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Requested resource not found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // When Http response code is '500'
                    else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Something went wrong at server end",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error Occured \n Most Common Error: \n1. Device not connected to Internet\n2. Web App is not deployed in App server\n3. App server is not running\n HTTP Status code : " +
                            statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }@
    Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        // Dismiss the progress bar when application is closed
        if (prgDialog != null) {
            prgDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

edited
logcat after the app crashed

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.habibah.uploadtoserverv4, PID: 3840
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1504-0F18:8MSFDPo.jpg flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.habibah.uploadtoserverv4/com.example.habibah.uploadtoserverv4.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3577)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3620)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.habibah.uploadtoserverv4.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:56)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3573)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3620) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: 'upload file other than images.'. Do you mean 'upload a file other than an image file'? The content or type of a file does not matter. If you can upload one file then you can upload all files. So what did you do wrong?

Comment: can you add the stack trace of the exception? You can find it in the log, after the app crashed

Comment: Even for uploading an image you have way to complicated code. And moreover you are not uploading an image but a base64 string.   You have a 'filePath'. That's enough. But you are putting the contents of that file in an imageView: 'imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));'. And after that you use Bitmapfactory again. Messing around with bitmaps. An  AsyncHttpClient(); can post with little effort files too.

Comment: what error message you got?

Comment: @greenapps yes I want to upload other than image file. from the link, it only allow images. I think it's because of

 // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);

and then I changed some of this part like in the question

Comment: No. I already explained you what you had to change. Continue with 'filePath'. Do not use ImageViews, Bitmaps or BitmapFactories to upload that file indicated by 'filePath'. Just hand over 'filePath' to an AsyncHttpClient.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin logcat?

Comment: yes. check what error message you got now?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin added logcat in post

Comment: you got a `NullPointerException` on `MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:56)` so `viewFileName` is `null`

Comment: how do you actually want to access the file you want to upload?

Comment: can you simplify the error message?